# Get values from an html document in C#

Tags: c#, html

My HTML is like this:

```
<i>Real Name:</i> Marcos Barbosa<br>
<i>Country:</i> BR<br>
<i>Account Created:</i> 03 Sep 2012<br>
<i>Last Logoff:</i> 20 Mar 2016<br>
<i>Status:</i> Online<br>
<i>Visibility:</i> Public<br>
```

Which the simplest way to get the values ​​within /i> br> ?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Are you able to alter your HTML to utilize input tags instead of just plain text?

Comment: Actually no, It is an HTML generated by search.

Answer (score 1):

If it is this simple, you can use regular expressions. Otherwise, you can use Html Agility Pack.

For example, using regular expressions, you can match:

```
<i>Real Name:</i>(.+?)<br>
```

or

```
<i>Real Name:</i>([^<]+)<br>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use .Net Framework's built in XmlDocument Parser. First, create an xml document like so:

```
            System.Xml.XmlDocument d = new XmlDocument();
            d.LoadXml(html);
```

Then you can access the data easily by selecting nodes.
You will need to re-format your data a little bit for it to be parsed, though. (`<br>` tags need to be closed, etc...)

Formatting your data like this would work:

```
<data>
<i>Real Name:</i><a> Marcos Barbosa</a>
<i>Country:</i><a> BR</a>
<i>Account Created:</i><a> 03 Sep 2012</a>
<i>Last Logoff:</i><a> 20 Mar 2016</a>
<i>Status:</i><a> Online</a>
<i>Visibility:</i><a> Public</a>
<i>Visibility:</i><a> Public</a>
</data>
```